# "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, compiler-errors

Just got a problem while building xcode workspace file.
I got this file from a friend. He has macOS Mojave and the latest Xcode version while I have macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.1.

Whenever I tried to build, I encountered this message:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.

I tried everything on google but I couldn't solve the issue

It's supposed to show iPhone simulator.

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

Comment: macOS 10.16.3? Are you sure?

Comment: oh sorry for typo it's 10.13.6

Comment: Hi, I am facing Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code with expo constants. Do you manage to fix that